# Why redux is limit the scope of the state inside reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm learning react and redux at the moment and come into an issue when I want to dispatch an action, but I need an access to global state inside of the reducer.

Obviously, I can get what I want by accessing a global state via thunk, but it kind of makes me wonder why would redux limit the scope of the state inside a reducer? What is the reasoning behind this decision?

Thanks

Comment: technically there is only one big reducer. but the big reducer can be split up into many smaller ones to make state management easier. the same reason why any function would have scoped variables. it's not a limitation of redux, you can always write a middleware that has access to the entire state object

Comment: thanks @azium, so the core reasoning for this is to make state management easier. Got it. Are there any concerns to use thunk purely for the sake of accessing global state, maybe?

Comment: the only concern is if that becomes the status quo then you're back to spaghetti logic. as long as you do this where it makes sense and leave good comments it's totally fine

Comment: @azium got it, thanks a lot buddy. I would love to set your answer as correct one if you'll decide to make an answer.

Comment: nah this is nothing new. it's actually one of the points listed in the docs for how to use thunks https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#thunk-use-cases . the general rule is use reducers where ever possible -- for everything else there's middleware

Comment: @azium Got it. Thanks a lot for the your help buddy.